# How can I add a footer to my website similar to the header?

Tags: html, css, footer

http://jsfiddle.net/Zj59M/

How can I duplicate that box and put it on the bottom as a footer?

I tried to wrap it in a div and just copy the stylesheet of the heade, but It doesn't work

```
<div id="footer">
 <p>This is my footer</p>
</div>
```

and this is my css

```
.footer {
 background: #ecf0f1;
 margin: 35px 25px;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Your CSS refers to a class (`.footer`) yet your HTML only has an ID (`#footer`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a class instead of id.

```
<div class="footer">
    <p>This is my footer</p>
</div>
```

Try using

```
<footer class="footer">
    <p>This is my footer</p>
</footer>
```

Or refer this video for visual assistance

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqOOOMeGb5A

Answer (score 0):

If you change your markup to:

```
<div class="footer">
    <p>This is my footer</p>
</div>
```

That will fix it.

You're referencing an ID in the markup and a class in your CSS.